# How can we implement Event tracing debugging for Windows (ETW) in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, web8.5

Currently, we are using SDL WEB 8. 
We came to know that SDL is providing The (ETW) event tracing debugging for Windows feature.
How can we implement the same in Web 8.0 version we have seen this in SDL Release Blog with partial support, but whereas the Web 8.5 is having full support.
could you please how we can leverage them and implement in my platform/system?

Below is the video link posted in youtube with limited information.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWqbrNgrzs0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the SDL Web 8 docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B80A337C-1D7A-440D-BBE6-A02D7EA89981

The docs talk about a "tracing tool", but that's not the nice visual GUI which you see demonstrated in the video; that tracing GUI is an open source project: https://github.com/sdl/web-tracevisualizer

Comment: Thanks Rick Pannekoek , i will go through the documentation and github link....And try incorporate in my dev sandbox.

Comment: Are there any configurations to enable/disable tracing? If so, what is that configuration file name, element name, attributes, options?
Do we need to restart the services to use ETW tracing?
Our environment is having primary / secondary CME servers. In this case, will ETW trace available in primary/secondary?
There were few cases where Tridion services stopped when the component is previewed. Will ETW trace help in identifying which component has caused stopping of services?
Is there any performance overhead due to ETW tracing?

Comment: That is 6 additional Questions in a comment. That is not practical; please create a separate Question for it.